# How to catch file opening eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm new at plugin development. I have my own editor for files *.example.
I extend `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` to edit it.

I want to catch the moment when this file is opened and post it to log (something like "file new.example is opened). But I really don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override the `init` method of the editor and use the editor input parameter:

```
@Override
public void init(final IEditorSite site, final IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {

    super.init(site, input);

    if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
      IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();

      // TODO log the IFile
    }
}
```

Note: The editor input is not always `IFileEditorInput`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732542/2670892) for more details.

Comment: Overriding `protected void doSetInput(IEditorInput input)
                   throws CoreException` would handle the cases where the editor is reused.